# docker: Percona how to populate mysql server with initial data

Tags: docker, percona

I have created percona container in the following way:

> docker run --name=sql  -v
> /path/to/dump:/tmp/dump:ro -d -e MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=True -e MYSQL_DATABASE=config percona:5.6 mysqld
> --max-allowed-packet=100M

Where the /tmp contains all data I need for restoring the dump. But I am getting error when trying to:

> docker exec 75c4b8880156
> /usr/bin/mysql -uroot config < /tmp/dump/performance_db.sql
>
> bash: /tmp/dump/performance_db.sql: No such file or directory

Even despite the fact that the file is there:

> $ docker exec 75c4b8880156 ls /tmp/dump/
>
> performance_db.sql

And I can even less/tail the content :(

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use the db initialization method recommended by [Percona Docker image docs, "Initializing a fresh instance" section](https://hub.docker.com/_/percona/): put your init script in a directory mounted as `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d`.